# Setting WordPress Title into Two Separate Variables

Tags: php, wordpress, explode

I have a custom post type that has a bunch of posts all formatted like so

```
 Artist - Song Title
```

for example

```
The Smashing Pumpkins - Quiet
```

I am trying to put 'Artist' in a variable $artist and 'Song Title' in a variable $song

```
 $artistsong = get_the_title();
 $songeach = explode("-", $artistsong);
 $artist = $songeach[0];
 $song = $songeach[1];
```

But this does not work. Echo-ing $artist gets the full title

```
The Smashing Pumpkins - Quiet
```

and echoing $song does not output anything

This works if I am just starting from plaintext, but not with 'get_the_title()'

```
 $song = "The Smashing Pumpkins - Quiet";
 $songeach = explode("-", $song);
 $artist = trim($songeach[0]);
 $song = trim($songeach[1]);
 echo $artist;
         //echos 'The Smashing Pumpkins'
 echo $song;
         //echos 'Quiet'
```

Is there another way to put the full title into a variable initially other than get_the_title() which does not seem to be working for me, or am I missing something else?

Comment: you sure that's a "dash" character, and not something different like `&ndash;` or `&mdash;`?

Comment: Where you insert this code?

Comment: Marc B - I echo'd get_the_title() and copied the dash that was presented in my code editor.

Comment: Quỳnh - on a single post template single-whatever.php

Comment: @bbruman Try my source bro xD I had success in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your `functions.php`

```
function get_the_title_keep_hyphen( $post = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    $title = isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
    $id = isset( $post->ID ) ? $post->ID : 0;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( ! empty( $post->post_password ) ) {

            /**
             * Filter the text prepended to the post title for protected posts.
             *
             * The filter is only applied on the front end.
             *
             * @since 2.8.0
             *
             * @param string  $prepend Text displayed before the post title.
             *                         Default 'Protected: %s'.
             * @param WP_Post $post    Current post object.
             */
            $protected_title_format = apply_filters( 'protected_title_format', __( 'Protected: %s' ), $post );
            $title = sprintf( $protected_title_format, $title );
        } elseif ( isset( $post->post_status ) && 'private' == $post->post_status ) {

            /**
             * Filter the text prepended to the post title of private posts.
             *
             * The filter is only applied on the front end.
             *
             * @since 2.8.0
             *
             * @param string  $prepend Text displayed before the post title.
             *                         Default 'Private: %s'.
             * @param WP_Post $post    Current post object.
             */
            $private_title_format = apply_filters( 'private_title_format', __( 'Private: %s' ), $post );
            $title = sprintf( $private_title_format, $title );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter the post title.
     *
     * @since 0.71
     *
     * @param string $title The post title.
     * @param int    $id    The post ID.
     */
    return $title;
}
```

And use this code in your `single.php`

```
$artistsong = get_the_title_keep_hyphen();
$songeach = explode(" - ", $artistsong);
$artist = $songeach[0];
$song = $songeach[1];
```

See the last line

I change from `return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );` to `return $title;`

Because `apply_filters` function change the hyphen from `-` => `–`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the dash symbol.

Try `$songeach = explode("P", $artistsong);` and you'll see what I mean. You could try a different character between artist and song title - although probably not ideal.